# How to reference id when dynamically using createComponent

Tags: angular, dynamic-content

I have followed the tutorial over at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#!#dynamic-loading and it´s working just fine.

But now I need the host element to be in a *ngFor and I cant figure out how to reference the unique id..?

```
<div fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="33%" fxFlex.gt-md="20%" *ngFor="let ad of adList">
  <div>{{ad.title}}</div>
  <template ad-host id="{{ ad.id }}"></template>
</div>
```

Edit: 
To illustrate it better I created a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/D1q7Al60m4UK1weRlcmQ?p=preview

So what I want to achieve is that when you click the name.
More info should appear below.

Right now it just finds the first [person-host] selector.

Comment: Question is really unclear? What do you want to achieve? Why do you need the HTML-Attribute id? What's wrong with `id="{{ ad.id }}"`?

Comment: I want to list all ads and if user clicks a title (there is a click event on that div) then I want the <template> to be populated with the data for that ad. So I´m not sure how to target a selector with matching id Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: Why not just placing the person-host directive on another div? http://plnkr.co/edit/znzRCu0xzOuhouiBYUg6?p=preview

Comment: Hmm... not sure how that helps.. issue is that if I click the second item on the first row I want to display the details between the first and second row.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way

```
<div *ngFor="let ad of adList">
    <my-ad [ad]="ad"></my-ad>
</div>
```

In your my-ad component you place

```
<template ad-host></template>
```

and load the ad.component into the ad-host placeholder.

Comment: This could work.. problem is that I´m using md-card (material design) and don´t want to hack it. Also it does not fit semantically :/

Comment: Where do you use md-card?

Comment: Where you use <my-ad [ad]="ad"></my-ad>

Comment: The issue is that I need to inject to the proper element.. right now it get´s injected into the first element with ad-host property.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you right, you want something like this:

```html
<div fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.gt-sm="33%" fxFlex.gt-md="20%" *ngFor="let ad of adList">
  <div (click)="ad.show = true;">{{ad.title}}</div>
  <template [ngIf]="ad.show" ad-host id="{{ ad.id }}"></template>
</div>
```

You should use angulars toolbox instead of any js-id-reference-selectors :)